# Copying Silverstripe dev site to live

Tags: silverstripe

My newly migrated live site can only be accessed one the homepage and /admin - i'm not able to login.

I have tried to do /dev/build og the ?flush=1. Didn't help.

My site is a subdomain, so I don't know if this plays some role in failing to access all the other pages?

I have set the SS_ENVIRONMENT_TYPE to live and I there's DB connection.

So my question is: what am I missing since I can only access homepage and /admin?

Comment: try SS_ENVIRONMENT_TYPE dev and see if there is some error logged. Do you see a menu? What error is shown when you try to access something else?

Comment: I don't see any other errors than HTTP's 500. I don't get any debug errors when changing the environment type to dev. Am I missing something?

Comment: a 500 can be pretty anything. Enable [php error reporting](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5438125/4137738) and check apache error log or php log.

Comment: Fatal error: Cannot use 'Int' as class name as it is reserved in /var/www/molsmedia.com/public_html/framework/model/fieldtypes/Int.php on line 8

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SilverStripe 3.6 and up supports PHP7.

See: https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/3/changelogs/3.6.0/

**Outdated:**

Silverstripe 3.X does not support PHP7 officially.

However, [this module](https://github.com/lekoala/silverstripe-327) will patch your code to avoid the 'Int' class name reserved error and whatnot. Just be aware that other third party modules might not work.

In addition it has been blogged about [here](http://www.silverstrip.es/blog/more-speed-with-php7-on-silverstripe-3/) for more detail.

Comment: When switching a site from 5.x to 7 be sure to delete the cache. Had once a timeout with that patch in production. Other projects run fine with it. Disclaimer: I wrote that module (not the patch, see the above linked blog post)